# Button changes label.text; no prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

Long story short. Massive app that uses a container and the notorious "empty segue". The container takes NSNotificationCenter notifications to perform segues off of a subclassed NSObject that contains the segues. This means the method "prepareForSegue" is not being used and if used, does nothing. NSNotification won't work on making the label.text value change if the view controller hasn't been placed on the stack yet, therefore I need something that will go first round. Here's the story:

View controller 1 has 2 buttons that when clicked will take you to view controller 2. View Controller 2 has a label that will change text depending upon which button you select. PrepareForSegue method cannot be used due to implementation of NSNotificationCenter and a container that is the listener.

I've tried using NSNotificationCenter, but as stated before, only works once the view controller has made it to the stack. I need the change to happen the first time. Thanks.

I have an IBAction tied to a button and that IBAction contains the NSNotification to swap my view controllers. The userinfo: takes a NSDictionary with objects and keys of the subclassed Segue (NSObject) that I created for the empty segues. The ContainerView controller has the observers in it for the notifications that will make the segues happen.

Comment: Can you give an example of how your Notification system works to push new views? Without that info, it's hard to say what would need to change to get the info from VC1 to VC2.

Comment: Added more content to the original post.

Comment: Your overall structure is still not clear. What controller has the container view? What is the purpose of the "empty segue", and why are you using a subclassed NSObject?  It might be helpful to see an image of your storyboard.

Comment: http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Comment: That's the empty segue link. I guess the easier question, is how to make a button change a label's text on another view controller when you can't use prepareForSegue.

Comment: Could another question be… can you re-think your app's structure so you *can* use prepareForSegue? Have your `subclassed NSObject` have a delegate that is the viewController that presents the next one, for example?

Comment: The reason for the container is because we have a header and footer that never change in the app. The container is size to fit in between the two so using a segue wasn't possible.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be using the same setup that is proposed in the sandmoose.com link, where he is able to use prepareForSegue. Why use a subclassed NSObject?

Comment: That prepare for segue is in the Container view controller and the notifications tell it to do the segues. You can't use the segue method in the other view controller classes.

Answer (score 0):

I made a set of parameters in the notification that did the segue. In the receiving view controller, a get parameter method performs an 'if' statement before anything is done to check those parameters and set the label text properly.